# Several change list in the same page

Tags: django, django-admin

In a custom admin page, I would like to have three change_lists (from three different models) on the same page. How could I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can always add your own views or extend the views that already exist on your models. contrib.auth provides decorators to protect your custom admin views as well. Take a close look at the [documentation for the admin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/admin/), and I think you'll have the answer to your question. Happy coding!